# Public SOAP web service that has Basic Authentication or OAuth

Tags: soap, oauth, wsdl, basic-authentication

I want to test a public SOAP web service that uses Basic Authentication or OAuth (preferably OAuth 2)  for authentication.

If anyone has any wsdl urls/files for same, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Try link [here](http://soatest.parasoft.com/services/). Find `username` and `password` in documentation too.

Comment: link is broken!